# How to find the displacement at each interface of a composite structure subjected to shear force?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, structural-analysis, applied-mechanics, solid-mechanics

Imagine a block made of 3 horizontal layers of 3 different materials (shear moduli S1, S2, S3) and fixed at the bottom surface.
If I apply a displacement 'x1' (or shear stress 'V1') to the top layer, how can I calculate the displacements at the interface between layer 1-2 or 2-3?

P.S. this is NOT a homework problem, and it is fine if you direct me to the correct resource. Really looking for some help to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

lets say the layers are from bottom 1st with thickness and shear moduli $ L_1, S_1$  2nd layer $L_2 , S_2$ and 3rd $L_3, S_3$

### -1

The applied shear $V_1 \ $ will be the same for all 3 layers and the shear displacement for each layer will be proportional to

$\text{deflection}_n =L_n\frac{V_1}{S_n}$

And total deflection is the Sun of all three deflections.

### -2

If we apply deflection of $x $
to the top, it will be distributed proportionally to the reverse stiffness of each layer exactly like springs in series.

$$K_n= \frac{S_n}{L_n}$$
$$x=\frac{F}{K_{eff}}$$
$$\frac{1}{K_{eff}}= \frac{1}{K_1}+\frac{1}{K_2}+\frac{1}{K_3}$$
And each layer will be deflected

$$x_n= x\frac{\frac{1}{K_n}}{\frac{1}{K_{eff}}}$$